# Vertical scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

I am coding a website but i'm not sure why the webpage is able to scroll horizontally slightly.

HTML & CSS code are below:

```css
<?php
// CSS Fil:





?>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Jquery css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- Fontawesome.io CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
 html {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 100%;
 }
 body {
   /* Margin bottom by footer height */
   margin-bottom: 60px;
   overflow-y: hidden; // hide vertical
   overflow-x: hidden; // hide horizontal
 }
 .footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
   height: 60px;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
 }
 

 
 body {
    background-image: url("images/vortrex-bg.png");
    background-size: cover;
 }
 
 .footer {
  background: none;
 }
 .footer-p {
  color: black;
  
 }
 .footer-link {
  color: red;
 }
 .footer-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkred;
 }
 .navbar-default {
  background: grey;
  border-color: grey;
 }
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: darkgrey;
 }
 
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
 color: none;
 }
 
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a,
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a:hover {
  color: black;
  background: darkgrey !important;
 }
 .img-circle {
 margin: -7px;
 }  
 h3 .online-text {
  color: green;
 }
 h3 .offline-text {
  color: red;
 } 

</style>
```

```html
<?php include('config/setup.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <header>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <?php include('config/css.php'); ?>
  <?php include('config/js.php'); ?>
  
  <title>Home | Vortrex</title>
   
 </header>
 <body>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="side-box-left">
     Teamspeak3 Class
    <?php
    /* try
     {
        
       // show server as online
       echo "Server Status: online<br />\n";
       echo "Server IP: " . $ts3->getAdapterHost() . ":" . $ts3->virtualserver_port . "<br />\n";
       echo "Server Name: " . $ts3->virtualserver_name . "<br />\n";
       echo "Server Uptime: " . TeamSpeak3_Helper_Convert::seconds($ts3->virtualserver_uptime) . "<br />\n";
       echo "Server Version: " . TeamSpeak3_Helper_Convert::version($ts3->virtualserver_version) . "<br />\n";
       echo "Current Clients: " . $ts3->virtualserver_clientsonline . " / " . $ts3->virtualserver_maxclients . "<br />\n";
     }
     catch(Exception $e)
     {
       // grab errors and show server as offline
       echo "Server Status: offline<br />\n";
     } */
    ?>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">  
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-circle" alt="Brand" src="images/logo.png" height="32" width="32"></a></div>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="statistik.php">Statistikker</a></li>
      <li><a href="/forum">Forum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav><!-- Slutningen af navbaren -->
     
    
     
     <!-- Overskrift på forsiden! -->
     
     <h1 align="center">Velkommen til Vortrex</h1>
     
     <!-- Overskrift på forsiden! -->
     
     <!-- I mellen <p> og </p> skrives hvad der skal stå på forsiden! -->
     <br>
     <br>
     <h3 align="center">Nyheder</h1>
     <p align="center">
      
      <?php #SKRIV HERUNDER! ?>
      
      
      <?php #SKRIV HEROVER! ?>
     </p>
     <!-- I mellen <p> og </p> skrives hvad der skal stå på forsiden! -->
   

      
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="side-box-right">
   <?php
   
   $q = "SELECT * FROM server";
   $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    
    if($r) {
     
    
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    
    $online = $rows['online'];
    $status = $rows['status'];
    
    if($rows['status'] == 'online') {
    echo "<h3 class='online-text'>$status:</h3> <h3>$online / 200</h3>";
    echo "<h4>mc.vortrex.dk</h4>";
    } else {
     echo "<h3 class='offline-text'>$status</h3>";
     echo "<h4>mc.vortrex.dk</h4>";
    }
    }
    } else {
    echo "<h2>Der skette en fejl</h2>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h4>Kontakt et staff medlem!";
   
    }
   
   ?>
   </div>
  </div> 
</div> 
    
    <?php include(D_TEMPLATE.'/footer.php'); ?> 
    
    <!--<div id="console-debug">
     Test debug window
    </div>-->

 </body>
</html>
```

The website is programmed on my localhosted PC but if you want to see it online you can find it on http://92.222.85.81/

Comment: I don't see a vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Im sorry i have to upload it to my new site. I will update this in a sec.

My FTP access is restricted.

Should be up within 15-30 minutes

Comment: Look at this one instead

http://92.222.85.81/

Comment: Still no scroll bar for me.

Comment: I just noticed at the very bottom a horizontal scroll bar. I cant edit the css on my side in web developer tools to edit it correctly.

Comment: Its just weird to me since there is not any html code that long which goes out there. So i am unaware where it comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean horizontal scrollbar?

It looks like your `.row` is not inside a `.container` element (assuming it's Bootstrap). Because the class `row` adds negative margin, it's bumping that element out a bit. The `container` element (again, assuming this is bootstrap which it looks like it is) counters that properly.

So try adding:

`<div clsas="container"></div>`

just under `body` around all your `.row` content.

I recommend reading the [Bootstrap documentaiton](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). All the necessary classes are listed nicely in there for you.

"Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding."

---

UPDATE: On an unrelated note to the question; your `meta`, `title`, and `link` tags should be inside a `head` tag and not a `header` tag.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I didnt really know that this could cause this problem but it fixed it. Thanks!